# While turining on ssr in Urql clint Im geting the below error: Did not expect server HTML to contain a <a> in <div>

Tags: html, typescript, frontend, urql

**webpack-internal:///./node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:67 Warning: Did not expect server HTML to contain a  in .**
at div
at Styled(div) (webpack-internal:///./node_modules/@emotion/react/dist/emotion-element-4fbd89c5.browser.esm.js:44:73)
at div
at Styled(div) (webpack-internal:///./node_modules/@emotion/react/dist/emotion-element-4fbd89c5.browser.esm.js:44:73)
at Flex (webpack-internal:///./node_modules/@chakra-ui/layout/dist/esm/flex.js:25:5)
at NavBar (webpack-internal:///./src/components/NavBar.tsx:31:142)
at Index (webpack-internal:///./src/pages/index.tsx:25:96)
at withUrqlClient(Index) (webpack-internal:///./node_modules/next-urql/dist/next-urql.es.js:50:28)
at ColorModeProvider (webpack-internal:///./node_modules/@chakra-ui/color-mode/dist/esm/color-mode-provider.js:46:5)
at ThemeProvider (webpack-internal:///./node_modules/@emotion/react/dist/emotion-element-4fbd89c5.browser.esm.js:78:71)
at MyApp (webpack-internal:///./src/pages/_app.tsx:19:24)
at ErrorBoundary (webpack-internal:///./node_modules/@next/react-dev-overlay/lib/internal/ErrorBoundary.js:23:47)
at ReactDevOverlay (webpack-internal:///./node_modules/@next/react-dev-overlay/lib/internal/ReactDevOverlay.js:73:23)
at Container (webpack-internal:///./node_modules/next/dist/client/index.js:150:5)
at AppContainer (webpack-internal:///./node_modules/next/dist/client/index.js:639:24)
at Root (webpack-internal:///./node_modules/next/dist/client/index.js:764:24)strong text

```js
import { Box, Button, Flex, Link } from "@chakra-ui/react";
import React from "react";
import NextLink from "next/link";
import { useLogoutMutation, useMeQuery } from "../generated/graphql";
import { isServer } from "../util/isServer";
interface NaveBarProps {}

export const NavBar: React.FC<NaveBarProps> = ({}) => {
  const [{ fetching: logOutFatching }, logout] = useLogoutMutation();
  const [{ data, fetching }] = useMeQuery({
    pause: isServer(),
  });

  let body = null;
  console.log('DATA', data);
  
  if (fetching) {
  } else if (!data?.me) {
    body = (
      <>
        <NextLink href="/login">
          <Link color="white" mr={2}>
            login
          </Link>
        </NextLink>
        <NextLink href="/registration">
          <Link color="white" mr={2}>
            Register
          </Link>
        </NextLink>
      </>
    );
  } else {
    body = (
     <>
     <Flex>
        <Box mr={3}>{data.me.username} </Box>
        <Button
        color = 'yellowgreen'
          onClick={() => {
            logout();
          }}
          isLoading={logOutFatching}
          variant="link"
        >
          logout
        </Button>
      </Flex>
      </>
    );
  }
  return (
    <>
    <Flex bg="tomato" p={4}>
      <Box ml={"auto"}>{body}</Box>
    </Flex>
    </>
  );
};
```

Comment: Hey, it would be good if you can give some background of the problem.  Possibly some code snippet which would helps others to reproduce and debug the problem on their end.  I appreciate that you pasted stack trace but simply pasting that won'f do good!

Answer (score 4):

Ran into the same issue following Ben Awad's 14 hour long tutorial on youtube. The problem is that the MeQuery is paused for SSR and therefore the userInfoBody is being setup incorrectly before the client renders it after receiving the user data. Simple fix is to use the same isServer check on the userInfoBody setup:

```
let userInfoBody = null;
if (isServer() || fetching) {
} ...
```

Answer (score 0):

For anyone attempting to solve this it is from Ben Awad's 14 hour long tutorial on youtube. I'm part way through this project and I'm getting this error myself and I've isolated it to being somewhere along the lines of: there is some inconsistency when rendering from the server and the client involving the NextLink's components.

Commenting out those two link's will fix the error. That's probably not the answer you are looking for but someone else may be able to chime in here. I'll also give this some time over the next few days!

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Instead of
`if (fetching) { }`,
add the useRouter hook: `const { isReady } = useRouter();` and write
`if (fetching || !isReady) { }`.
This is some router issue with next.js